# What does straight line general equation coefficients a, b, c mean

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

This is the straight line general equation:

$\color{red}a x + \color{red}b y + \color{red}c = 0$

What does the coefficients $\color{red} a, \color{red}b, \color{red}c$ mean and what them names?

Comment: $-\frac{a}{b}$ is the slope, $-\frac{c}{a}$ is the x-intercept and $-\frac{c}{b}$ is the y-intercept.

Comment: The coefficients $a$ and $b$ are also the components of a vector perpendicular to the straight line. Knowing this you can quickly check from two straight lines equations if they are parallel or perpendicular (by using the scalar product), for example. This is explained in detail in Pogorelov's book "Geometry".

Comment: Explained a bit [here](http://portal.tpu.ru:7777/SHARED/k/KONVAL/Sites/English_sites/G/l_Plane_f.htm) and [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Calculus/StraightLine.shtml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be all the points $(x, y)$ that satisfy your equation. You expect $E$ to be a line.

However, if $a = b = 0$ then
1) if $c = 0$ any pair $(x, y)$ satisfies the equation, so $E$ is actually the whole plane.
2) if $c \neq 0$ then no pair $(x, y)$ can salvage the situation that the equation says $c = 0$, so $E$ is actually the empty set.

So let us now assume that either $a$ or $b$ is nonzero.

If $a = 0$ then you have $b y = c$, which fixes the $y$ coordinate; therefore $E$ is a line parallel to the $x$-axis and lies $c/b$ units to the north of it (to the south, if that number is negative).

A similar situation occurs if $b = 0$.

So, now assume that both, $a$ and $b$ are nonzero. Then it is more convenient to  rewrite your equation as $\frac{x}{A} + \frac{y}{B} = 1$, where $A = -c/a$ and $B = -c/b$. The new equation says: if $x = 0$ then $y = B$; if $y = 0$ then $x = A$; so the line goes through the points $(0, B)$ and $(A, 0)$.

You can see that the parameter $c$ gauges the distance of the line to the origin.

I don't know about the *names* for $a$, $b$ and $c$.
But I would say $A$ is the $x$-intercept and $B$ is the $y$-intercept.